# Why would a Rocky Mountain Goat be making scrapes in the ground?

Tags: animal-behaviour, nevada, rocky-mountain-goats

While hiking in the Ruby Mountains of Nevada, I came around the corner and saw several mountain goats who had made several fairly large scrapes (3-4 ft long and a couple feet wide) in the ground.

[image]

[image]

Why would the mountain goats have done this?

Comment: One thing that hasn't been mentioned in the answers below is that they may be trying to access salts/minerals to ingest. I know deer and other animals do this in different locations.

Answer (score 5):

Because they like it.  It feels good, so they do it.

> Many mammals roll in sand or dirt, presumably to keep parasites away or to help dry themselves after exercise or becoming wet. A sand roll, which is a stall or yard covered with deep sand, is traditionally included as part of stable complexes for use by racehorses after exercise.[20]
>
> Dust bathing has been suggested to have a communicatory function in several mammals [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_bathing#Mammals)

When I raised goats I don't recall ever seeing a goat take a dirt bath.  But Googling around finds several accounts of it.

Comment: Could also be that they were going to lay there, as the ground underneath the first layer is generally cooler, or a combination of both.

Answer (score 2):

I have observed these, I have seen dogs, goats, cats, wolves, etc scraping the ground. In some cases they sat onto it. In some cases they didn't.
Following are cases where it makes sense:

1. Sharpening their hooves - Thats one way they sharpen their hooves periodically. I have seen our dog and cat scraping the ground, possibly with an intention to make the nails blunt (If we don't cut them first!).
2. Marking - I am not sure about goats, but many mammals use this to mark their presence.
3. A little scraping of ground allows the animal to sleep/sit on the surface which is comparatively softer, warmer or cooler (depends on season/geography)
4. A very common but rarely noticed scenario: Talking to villager who had 100s of goats, I asked him why a goat is seen stamping the ground or scraping the ground. Stamping had multiple meanings. He told me that sometimes something gets stuck in their hooves, and scraping a surface helps them get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Goats are mineral deficient and will often scrape and lick areas that contain urine to acquire needed salts.  https://www.fs.usda.gov/detail/olympic/home/?cid=stelprdb5412239